# .html() not working in async code

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, callback

I have some code sort of like this:

```
function myFunction(){
    $('#somediv').html("Making request...");
    $.get('/script.php',
        function(data){
            if(data.error == 0){
                $('#somediv').html("yay!");
            } else {
                $('#somediv').html("oops!");
                window.setTimeout(myFunction(), 2000);
            }
        },
        'json'); 
}
```

The "oops!" never displays, I believe possibly because the $.get() request is being called asynchronously. The only way I can make it display is if I wrap it in a window.setTimeout() or run an alert() before it.

Comment: "oops" never displays???

Comment: $('#somediv').html("oops!");

Comment: Are you sure the success method is actually called?

Comment: Whats being returned from your `$.get` call? `console.log(data);` in your callback

Comment: It's more likely that your script isn't returning json, and hence isn't getting to the complete callback. Can we see `script.php`?

Comment: Object {error: 1} is the log

Comment: If you create a script that just returns 'error' => 1 you can replicate.

Comment: You're immediately re-executing myfunction, which immediately sets it's html to "Making Request..." again, deleting "oops". Please, start debugging by following the code line by line.

Comment: We got a winner ^^^^ Missed that @KevinB!

Comment: @KevinB sorry, I actually thought of that and in my code I have a window.setTimeout(). It still does the same thing though.

Comment: setTimeout isn't a fix unless you're delaying calling myfunction.

Comment: No because you're using setTimeout incorrectly.

Comment: Oh, I am? Could you elaborate?

Comment: `myFunction()` returns `undefined`, so `window.setTimeout(myFunction(), 2000);` is same with `window.setTimeout(undefined, 2000);`. [Right](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20958423/1420197)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow your code line by line, and you'll understand what's happening.

```
function myFunction(){
    $('#somediv').html("Making request...");
    $.get('/script.php',
        function(data){
            if(data.error == 0){
                $('#somediv').html("yay!");
            } else {
                $('#somediv').html("oops!");
                myFunction();
            }
        },
        'json'); 
}
```

1. `$('#somediv').html("Making request...");`
2. `$.get()`
3. `// waiting for ajax request...`
4. `$('#somediv').html("oops!");`
5. `$('#somediv').html("Making request...");`

steps 4 and 5 are happening within .01 ms most likely, which is why you never see "oops!".

You can use a settimeout around `myfunction` to make oops visible, but it would likely be better to instead just not display anything so that it just continues to say "Making Request...".

Comment: Hey thanks. I thought of this and added a window.setTimeout() (I forgot to include it in my example code. However, the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
window.setTimeout(myFunction, 2000);
```

instead of

```
window.setTimeout(myFunction(), 2000)
```

`window.setTimeout(myFunction(), 2000);` calls `myFunction()` and it's same with: `window.setTimeout(undefined, 2000)` because `myFunction()` returns `undefined`.

But when `myFunction` is called you rewrite the html using `$('#somediv').html("Making request...");`.